# Почему программа выводит старый список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция, модифицирующая список. Вывод показывает, что список не изменился.

```
def modify_list(l):
    a = []
    for i in l:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            a.append(i//2)
    return a
lst = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(lst)
print(lst)
```

Comment: ну раз вы хотите чтобы именно переменную `lst` выводил новую то приравняйте ее `lst = modify_list(lst)`

Comment: Эта строка modify_list(lst) вызывает функцию, но не переопределяет массив. поместите вызов функции в print и всё заработает или присвойте вызов старой функции

Answer (score 0):

решено

```
def modify_list(l):
    for i in range(len(l),0,-1):
        if l[i - 1] % 2 == 0:
            l[i - 1] = l[i - 1] //2
        else:
            l.remove(l[i - 1])
    return l
```

Comment: предыдущая функция была гораздо понятнее и идиоматичнее. Только пользоваться ей надо по-другому: `lst = modify_list(lst)`, как вам уже указали в комментариях... А еще лучше: `lst = [x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0]`